# Weblogic 12c ear application - load classes from weblogic or FMW modules

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, classloader

I am facing a *not-so-common* situation. Below is a sample structure of myApp.ear

`myApp.ear
  |-APP-INF
     |-lib
        |-myCode-package1.jar
        |-myCode-package2.jar
        |-commons-io.jar
        |-xercesImpl.jar
        |-xmlbeans.jar
        |-...
        |-...`

As you can see, our ear contains not just our code but also libraries/jars that are available in `<FMW_HOME>/wlserver/modules/` or `<FMW_HOME>/oracle_common/modules` or both in some cases.

We use very basic functionality from most of these 3rd party libraries in most cases. So, we are not keen on specific version of a library in general. I want to get rid of these 3rd party open source libraries that are being shipped along with myApp.ear despite being available in Weblogic.

Reasons for removing the 3rd parties -

- Our company mandated that we are supposed to bundle the latest version of the library available (probably due to security reasons). If we bundle them, if a 3rd party library is updated, then the responsibility of updating is ours. This is an overhead for us during every release and want to avoid that.
- Secondly, it will make our build/deploy faster and our app lighter too.

When I attempted to remove, I thought my ear class loader will automatically pickup required classes from Weblofic modules. Instead, I am getting all sorts ClassNotFound exceptions during server startup. I found a lot of articles/literature on `prefer-application-packages` or `prefer-web-inf-classes` etc which are exact reverse of my requirement.

I am probably missing something very basic (or doing something stupid :)) here.

Comment: Classpath issue. It is not because WebLogic provides these libraries it means they are automatically put in your application's classpath. You can add them to your server's classpath to make them available to your application.

Comment: You should maintain your own dependencies. The jars that come with WebLogic are part of it's implementation and can be changed/removed at Oracle's whim. WebLogic is only responsible for exposing the Java EE APIs to your application and nothing else.